# Django - How to get the object attribute before updating in Update class based view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm learning Django and I'm struggling with the Class Based View of Django.

I would like to access the object attributes before the update in order to show the user what was the previous attributes.

Here my class view :

```
class GroupUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = GroupName
    fields = ['name', 'description']
    template_name = 'dashboard/groups/group_update_form.html'
    group_name_before_editing ="" #I wanted to write model.name here

    #Overrive
    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, "The group %s was updated successfully" % (
        self.group_name_before_editing))
        return reverse_lazy('dashboard:group-update', args=(self.object.pk,))
```

In `get_success_url()`, I would like to show the user the previous name of the group that has been updated.

I tried also with the `get_context_data()` but was not able to obtain the result.

Could you help please ? How to get the current model attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GroupUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    ...
    group_name_before_editing ="" #I wanted to write model.name here
```

You can't put the code there, because it runs when the server starts and loads the module. You need to put the code inside a method that runs when Django handles the request.

I would suggest overriding the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method and setting the value at that point.

```
class GroupUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super().get_object(queryset)
        self.group_name_before_editing = obj.name
        return obj
```